# VBA waiting on OLE Action

Tags: excel, vba, ole

I'm pulling my hair out over my vba code waiting for an OLE Action, and it's being triggered on all of my forms that I run in this workbook. I have tried clicking "ignore applications that use DDE", I do not have any add-ons running, and I'm not sending anything or interacting with any program outside of Excel. Below is a sample code. I'm getting desperate and would love some help!

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim companyNumber, contactF1, LastName, title, Email, dphone, cphone, nextcontact As Integer
Dim List As Range: Set List = Worksheets("Database").Range("CompanyNames")
Dim contactrange As Range

companyNumber = WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1, List, 0) + 1 

LastName = 1
title = 2
Email = 3
dphone = 4
cphone = 5
nextcontact = 6

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set contactrange = Range(Worksheets("Database").Cells(companyNumber, editrange.Value), Worksheets("Database").Cells(companyNumber, editrange.Value + cphone))

Worksheets("Database").Cells(companyNumber, editrange.Value).Value = NewFName.Value
Worksheets("Database").Cells(companyNumber, editrange.Value + LastName).Value = NewLName.Value
Worksheets("Database").Cells(companyNumber, editrange.Value + title).Value = NewTitle.Value
Worksheets("Database").Cells(companyNumber, editrange.Value + Email).Value = NewContactEmail.Value
Worksheets("Database").Cells(companyNumber, editrange.Value + dphone).Value = NewDirectPhone.Value
Worksheets("Database").Cells(companyNumber, editrange.Value + cphone).Value = NewCellPhone.Value


    If CheckBox1 = True Then
        CreateCandidate.CandidateFName.text = EditContact.NewFName.text
        CreateCandidate.CandidateLName.text = EditContact.NewLName.text
        CreateCandidate.CandidateTitle.text = EditContact.NewTitle.text
        CreateCandidate.CandidateEmail.text = EditContact.NewContactEmail.text
        CreateCandidate.CandidateDphone.text = EditContact.NewDirectPhone.text
        CreateCandidate.CandidateCphone.text = EditContact.NewCellPhone.text
        CreateCandidate.Show
    Else
    End If

    If CheckBox2 = True Then
        contactrange.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        'add message box confirming deletion!!!!!!!!!
    Else
    End If

EditContact.Hide
editrange.Value = 7
MsgBox "Contact Edited" & vbNewLine & "Changes Saved"

    LookupForm.CNameSearch.text = EditContact.ComboBox1.text
    LookupForm.ContactSearchBtn = True

Call Clear_ALL_Controls
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: A little more detail on what you are trying to achieve? On what line does it stop? What program(s) do you use as references?

Comment: I have narrowed it down to: LookupForm.ContactSearchBtn = True as the culprit. "LookupForm.CNameSearch.text = EditContact.ComboBox1.text" is populating a company name into another form and then clicking the search button on that form in order to refresh the page.

Comment: If I step through it, it works fine. But when I run it at full speed I get the "waiting on OLE action" notice. If I comment out LookupForm.ContactSearchBtn = True and don't run that second form, it works